# Cannot read property 'NODE_ENV' of undefined in nodejs on https SSL

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, https

I have install the ssl certificate in my angular and nodejs project. but after installing the certificate i am unable to login into my application. My main index.js file is running perfectly, but when i am tried to login from my application, it showingn me 500 (Internal Server Error) with a message (Cannot read property 'NODE_ENV' of undefined). I am showing you the localhost but the same problem is coming on production.Please help me out here, how can i fix it.

[My error image of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Mta.png)

[My nodejs console working picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qiV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not HTTPS SSL problem.
Seems that the problem is on the file which defines a handler for POST `/login`, attach this file for more details.

Comment: What file do you need? index.js file or login file?

Comment: This is the link of my index.js file

https://gofile.io/?c=OEyBrQ

This the link of file which contain login function

https://gofile.io/?c=SpjIoG

Please help here.

Comment: Find across you sources `NODE_ENV` string, probably you did some typo in construction like `process.env.NODE_ENV` Also would be nice to have an error message

Comment: I have look into my all files but i didn't find NODE_ENV in it, it is working fine on http, the error occur on https.

Comment: Try to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666341/3984210) . The  `restify-https` last updated 5yrs ago so it might cause this error

Comment: I have already see this, and make my index.js file according to this and its run successfully.